# Salesforce Timecard entry API

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-service-cloud

I am planning to develop a salesforce mobile application for my company, which allows employees to enter their timecards on their go, I'm aware there are already few other apps by salesforce, available to do the same but I want to rebuilt it again for various reasons. Kindly let me know, if this is feasible? If feasible, kindly let me know the salesforce API which has to be used for doing the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above said requirement is completely feasible. I have implemented it.Some salesforce objects required for achieving it are pse__timcardheader__c, pse__timecard__c and few Rest APIs like process/action are required. Posting the answer for the benefit of others.